# Export SQL Server database to script using a command

Tags: export, sql-server-express

I need to export my database into a script file using a SQL command.

I'm using MS SQL Server 2010 Express.

Is it possible and if yes whats the command?

Answer (score 0):

This link may be of your use: [Generate Script with Data from Database](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/11/16/sql-server-2005-generate-script-with-data-from-database-database-publishing-wizard/). With it you can use publish command like:

```
sqlpubwiz script -d AdventureWorks “C:\AdventureWorks.sql”
```

However its quite easy to use [SQL Server Management Studio](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=7593) to export the database.